# Diameter of Euclidean Sphere using $||x||_p$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, optimization, metric-spaces

> Question: Given a real number $p$, $p \in [0, \infty] $, 
> What is the diameter of an Euclidean Sphere with respect to $||x||_p$?

Attempt: What quickly jumped out was the answer would be the max value of $||x||_p$ minus the minimum value of $||x||_p$, with $x_1^2+ x_2^2...x_n^2=1$, but I couldn't do it. I tried reducing this to the case of 2d, but failed.

What is the solution?

Comment: I think for the dual question, the maximum Euclidean diameter of the $p$-norm sphere (for $p \ge 2$) will be on the diagonal. Might this help?

Comment: @EthanBolker  This doesn't really help I can fine the 2d case, but I can't bring it up to the nth d

Comment: The diameter is $d = 2\alpha \| x \|_p$ such that $\|x\|_p=1$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @CroCo ∥x∥p isn't equal to 1,  $$x_1^2.+..x_n^2=1$$

Comment: @CroCo your answer doesn't make any sense. please expand it and show how you get it. :)

Comment: @CroCo what? $||x||_p=(x_1^p+x_2^p...x_n^p)^(1/p)$. You must be mistaken

Comment: yes this is true $\| x\|_p= (x_1^p+\cdots+x^p_n)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. Your question is not clear to me. What is wrong with $d=2\alpha\|x\|_p$ such that $\|x\|_p=1$. This clearly shows the relation between the diameter and the norm.

Comment: @CroCo Your answer just doesn't make any sense. Please show how you got this answer. the $\alpha$ just makes $d$ any number

Comment: How do you define an Euclidean sphere? For $\alpha$. It is just a scaling factor.

Comment: All vectors $(x_1,x_2....x_n)$, that satisfy $x_1^2+x_2^2....x_n^2=1$, form a n-dimensional Euclidean sphere

Comment: @CroCo   if the alpha is in the equation and alpha can be any real positive number, then the expression for D s also any real positive number which is nonsense

Comment: Based on your definition, what is the radius?

Comment: @CroCo I am using the def of Diameter that comes from the study of metric spaces. Radius or the def of circles do not appply

Comment: Your definition is for unit sphere in $n$ dimensional space; hence $r=\|x \|_p$ and the diameter is then $d=2r$, right?

Comment: @CroCo  No the diameter is defined as supremum of$ ||x-y|_p$ for x and y in the sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to maximizing $\|x-y\|_p$ subject to $\|x\|_2 = \|y\|_2 = 1$, where $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$.

Using symmetry, the above problem is equivalent to maximizing $2\|x\|_p$ subject to $\|x\|_2=1$.

Let us suppose $p\neq 2$, which is trivial. Using the Lagrange multipliers method, we have that $p x_k^{p-1} = 2\lambda x_k$ for every $k\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier.

If $x_k > 0$, then $x_k^{p-2} = 2\lambda/p$. Using that $\|x\|_2=1$ we have that $$x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n = 1/\sqrt{n}.$$

Which evaluates to
$$ 2\|x\|_p = 2\left(\frac{n}{n^{p/2}}\right)^{1/p} = 2\frac{\sqrt[p]{n}}{\sqrt{n}}. $$

On the other hand, we can have some $x_k = 0$ and others $x_k \neq 0$. This step must be better justified, but the case of interest is $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = x_3 = \dots = x_n = 0$, which evaluates to
$$ 2\|x\|_p = 2. $$

Therefore, by the extreme value theorem, we have that if $p < 2$, then the diameter is equal to $2\frac{\sqrt[p]{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ and if $p \ge 2$, then the diameter is equal to $2$.